# wifi extender with switch

Tags: switch, ieee-802.11

I have just moved office, to the sam building but about 50m down the corridor. I would like to have internet in my new office, but need to wait 1 month for my ISP to come out and move the line.

I am trying to figure out what i can do in the mean time. In the new office i will require a switch / hub as not all equipment is wifi ready.

Can i get some sort of wifi extender with an rj45 on it, that will sit in the new office and connect to the wifi in my old office?

Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could get a Wi-Fi bridge. The performance will be less than stellar.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for confirming, any internet is better than none!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are only talking 160 feet or so.  If you can get building management to get you a copper path patched through or dropped above the drop tile ceiling (if you have that) just move your AP.  Otherwise you can use a WiFi bridge without line of sight considering the following.

> Concrete and concrete block walls may limit signal penetration to
>   three or four walls. Wood or drywall typically allow for adequate
>   penetration through five or six walls. A thick metal wall reflects
>   signals, resulting in poor penetration. Steel-reinforced concrete
>   flooringwill restrict coverage between floors to perhaps one or two
>   floors.

source [cisco.com](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-antennas-accessories/product_data_sheet09186a008008883b.html)

Another possibility is to use 4G LTE cellular tethering.